# NSTableCellView not retaining the value of its NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nstableview, nstablecellview

The following is inside the delegate's viewForTableColumn method. I am dynamically creating table columns in the datasource based on a selection in a list view.

```
    NSDictionary* rowData = [[self tableData] objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString* identifier = [tableColumn identifier];

    NSTableCellView* result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"myCellView" owner:self];
    if (result == nil) {
        result = [[NSTableCellView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 90.0, 10.0)];
        _textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 90.0, 10.0)];
        [result setTextField:_textField];
        [[result textField] setStringValue:[rowData objectForKey:identifier]];
    }
    else {
        [[result textField] setStringValue:[rowData objectForKey:identifier]];
    }
    NSLog(@"result text field: %@", [[result textField] stringValue]);

    return result;
```

Now in

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView didAddRowView:(NSTableRowView *)rowView             forRow:(NSInteger)row {
NSLog(@"did add: %ld", row);
NSTableCellView* aView = [rowView viewAtColumn:0];
NSLog(@"%@", [[aView textField]stringValue]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[[rowView viewAtColumn:0 ] textField] stringValue]);
}
```

the textField is a Zombie. What gives? Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is that `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` method?

Comment: A method in NSTableView class

Comment: ah, my fault, was thinking UITableView instead. :)

Comment: I dont think you need to alloc init a new text field, by default a table view cell will have a label and an image cell if its added through Nib.

Comment: What happens if you want to avoid having a xib altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to get a reference (IBOutlet) for the NSTableCellView in the window controller. Thats about it, nothing else. Now I can access that via its identifier in the NSTableView delegate; the reference is retained even after removing all the columns and adding new columns to the tableview.

Now dealing with very abysmal tableview performance on a tables ranging from 300-3000 rows! That's for another day.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that when you do:

```
_textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 90.0, 10.0)];
```

you are causing a release of whatever was previoisly in `_textField`.